# How does IteratorBindingInitialization work?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Currently, I'm trying to figure out how TDZ happens when function parameters have default values:

```
function func(x = y, y = 1) {
    return ;
}

func(); // ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

I followed the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation), in step 21, x and y are bound in envRec but uninitialized (hasDuplicates is false). In step 25, the [IteratorBindingInitialization](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization) begins, but in the spec I didn't get that how the binding works, there is no something like GetValue, so why reference y fails or am I looking into the wrong definition of IteratorBindingInitialization?

Comment: AFIK in the given function you are trying to set an uninitialized `let/var` value to another. Hence the error.

Comment: A [`BindingElement` can be a `SingleNameBinding`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-BindingElement), whose evaluation is described here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization . `GetValue` is called there.

Comment: I guess it simply applies to both situations and they had to put it somewhere.

Comment: Thank @FelixKling for pointing out the right reference. But why arguments here processed as Array destructuring binding pattern is explained [here](http://es-discourse.com/t/why-function-call-might-not-always-mean-function-call/38/4).